# Phalcon ODM bulk delete

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

i'm wondering whether it's possible to make a bulk delete(using single operation) in phalcon ODM instead of fetching the documents and removing those one by one in a loop via 'delete()' method?

I need something like this:

```
$db->users->remove(array("type" => "abc"));
```

The official documentation says nothing about it as well as dumping class methods reveal no new info.

PS. I'm using phalcon 2.0.10

Comment: I was also wondering the same, however after some searching I did not find anything. Perhaps as a Plan B you can always make a method in a BaseModel which accepts Collection and WhereClause as parameters and iterates over the resultset. Just like the example in docs here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/odm.html#deleting-records Let us hope that someone else has better solution :)

Comment: As a workaround i've created a method and using the mongoclient 'remove()' directly, but really looking forward to something less dirty)

Comment: Hi Eugene Sue, can you please share your method, and tell us in which file to put it please :)

Answer (score 1):

Some people were asking to share the method i'm using

I've created a method in ModelBase. All other models extend it, so they have access to it's methods. I'm using a static function in order not to create an instance of the class.

```
class ModelBase extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection
{
    public static function deleteBulk(array $conditions)
    {
        $class = get_called_class();
        $model = new $class;
        $collection = $model->getSource();

        # I have a registered service mongo in DI, so i just get it from there
        $mongo = \Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->getMongo();

        return $mongo->$collection->remove($conditions);
    }
}
```

Then i have a model:

```
class Items extends ModelBase
{

}
```

So when i need to bulk delete, i just call:

```
Items::deleteBulk(array("type" => "abc"));
```

Comment: What if you renamed your table in your model? isn't it easier to call something like `$this->getSource()` in your base model instead of the `explode` ?